# How to read doubles from a .txt file

Tags: java

I'm able to read the string variables, but it won't read the double for some reason.  What can I do to make it read the double?

```
public class RundraiserApp
{

/**
 * @param args
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Fundraising[] dList = new Fundraising[10];

    String name = null;
    String address = null;
    String cityStateZip = null;
    double donation = 0;
    int i = 0, ctr = 0;

    Scanner in;
    File file = new File("Donations.txt");
    try
    {
        in = new Scanner(file);

        while (in.hasNext() && i < dList.length)
        {
            name = in.nextLine();
            address = in.nextLine();
            cityStateZip = in.nextLine();
            donation = in.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }
        ctr++;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you give example of input file?

Comment: Try reading it as `String` and then convert it to `double` using [`Double#parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source) at RundraiserApp.main(RundraiserApp.java:51)

Comment: @user2073662 If you add your input file structure then it will be easy to help you out. Also dont put errors in comment. You can edit your question and add that there.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your file structure below

```
Name
Address
Zip
2000.50
```

Change donation like.

```
donation = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
```

Comment: Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());  (lower case p in parseDouble)

Comment: @Taylor Thanks typo fixed.